# Delphi - How to break string concatenation into several lines

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, code-formatting, line-breaks

I have a long SQL text that I want to assign to a query SQL. I do this the following way:

```
SQL.Text:= 'SELECT T1.COLUMN1,T2.COLUMN2,T1COLUMN3..........,'+
          ' T1.COLUMNn FROM TABLE1 T1 INNER JOIN '+
          ' TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID=T2.ID'+
          ' WHERE T1.COLUMN10=100'
```

The actual SQL is 20 times longer than this. My problem is with the line breaks. When I format the source code (Ctrl+D) it sometimes leaves the lines as I typed, but other times it deletes the line breaks and I get something like this:

```
 'SELECT T1.COLUMN1,T2.COLUMN2,T1COLUMN3 ' + 'FROM TABLE1 T1 INNER JOIN '+  'TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID=T2.ID'
```

And this leads to a "line too long (more than 1023 charactes)" error. What's interesting is this does not happen with all lines. I can't catch the difference between the lines which will be affected and those that won't. I need a line break after or before the "+" sign. How do I do this?

Comment: what value of Formatter -> Delphi -> Line Breaks -> Right Margin  do you have? Default value (as I remember) is 80.

Comment: dou you really need to write long sql in code? you can create stored procedure in DB, or save SQL in Query-component (i.e in dfm file), or load from other file or resource.

Comment: @teran, Right Margin is 60. But no matter what value is there this problem does not happen with all lines. I know your SPs are the best option.I totally agree.

Comment: If the problem does not happen with all lines it could be that the line endings are not CRLF, but CR or LF. This would be common if the code was pasted from another program or file that had different line endings. This is a common problem with the IDE and setting break points. Did you paste the SQL code from somewhere?

Comment: No I did not. I have an SQL text and the problem occurs in some part of it. Even if I had pasted it from somewhere the problem would have to be with all the lines of the text.

Comment: Log this on QualityCentral as a BUG in the formatter. And use a different code formatter. :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to assign the value in every line:

```
SQL.Text := 'SELECT T1.COLUMN1,T2.COLUMN2,T1COLUMN3..........,';
SQL.Text := SQL.Text + ' T1.COLUMNn FROM TABLE1 T1 INNER JOIN ';
SQL.Text := SQL.Text + ' TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID=T2.ID';
SQL.Text := SQL.Text + ' WHERE T1.COLUMN10=100';
```

I know it looks ugly, but I think it solves your problem.

Comment: This results in runtime rather than compile time concatenation.

Comment: Instead of `SQL.Text := SQL.Text+....` you should better code `SQL.Add(....);` which is both faster and easier to read.

Comment: If you don't mind runtime concatenation, it would be easier, and look better to use `SQL.Add('SELECT...');`

Answer (score 14):

You can also use the Add function.

```
SQL.Clear;
SQL.ADD('SELECT T1.COLUMN1,T2.COLUMN2,T1COLUMN3..........,');
SQL.ADD(' T1.COLUMNn FROM TABLE1 T1 INNER JOIN');
SQL.ADD(' TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID=T2.ID');
SQL.ADD(' WHERE T1.COLUMN10=100');
```

Comment: Actually I've always used this approach. But after starting to use UniDac for Oracle connection I began getting errors when I Added SQL strings like this. That's why I decided to set SQL.Text directly.

Comment: Besides, this is not SQL.Text spcific thing, I could use this in any other case. I just wonder when strings concatinated with + signs gets formatted to one line.

Comment: If you want to set a breakpoint then set the breakpoint into the Tstrings. unit Classes.TStrings.SetTextStr. There you will see that TStrings.Text:= 'blabla'also use the Add function

Comment: While you're there, also put BeginUpdate and EndUpdate in.